# How to find 'URL' and append something at the end of URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, ampscript

In Data Extension one field 'HTML' have Data that I have shown below, Now I have to Find the 'Href', and and at the last of URL append some text like '&MC='. It may have Multiple 'Href'. Please help me on this.

```
<table width="540" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top">
   <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 2px; line-height: normal; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;">
   <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://test.4.com/testRegistration/testLobbyServlet?target=reg20.jsp&eventid=897605&sessionid=1&key=2F3D1EB963D9DB7738BF2877DFFDBA01&partnerref=Social&sourcepage=register&loc=zOTlocz&prod=zWAz&tech=zsecz&prog=zOTprogz&type=zOTtypez&media=zWCz&country=zUSz" alias="Success with Enterprise Mobility: Making email and Office 365 secure on mobile devices">
   Success with Enterprise Mobility: Making email and Office 365 secure on mobile devices 
   </a>
   </h5>
   <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">
   <span style="color: rgb(103, 103, 103);">
   <em>December 9, 2014, 10:30 A.M.&ndash;11:30 A.M. Pacific Time</em><br>
   An enterprise mobility strategy involves identity, management, and productivity. In this session featuring Brad Anderson, you will learn about the integration and the Office mobile apps while enabling secure mobile productivity.
   </span>
   </p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top">&nbsp;
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top">
   <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 2px; line-height: normal; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;">
   <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://test.TTr.com/?Wt.mc_id=IG15W2NWTN&loc=zOTlocz&prod=zWAz&prod=zWSz&tech=zCLz&prog=zOTprogz&type=zEVz&media=zOTmediaz&country=zUSz" alias="Test: Everything about enterprise technology under one roof">
   Test: Everything about enterprise technology under one roof
   </a>
   </h5>
   <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">
   <span style="color: rgb(103, 103, 103);">
   <em>May 4&ndash;8, 2015, Chicago, IL</em><br>
   If you&rsquo;re serious about technology, you don&rsquo;t want to miss Test. This event will be the intersection of everything in enterprise technology. Get ahead in your job and your career.
   </span>
   </p>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: HTML Field have data like this "href=http://blogs.xxyz.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx?loc=zatfz&prod=zNETz&tech=zWDz&lang=zVBNz&prog=zMSDNFz&type=zTrz&country=zUSz" and result should like this http://blogs.xxyz.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx?loc=zatfz&prod=zNETz&tech=zWDz&lang=zVBNz&prog=zMSDNFz&type=zTrz&country=zUSz&MC=HTML5&MC=Windows&MC=Sharepoint&MC=MSAzure&MC=WebDev

Comment: please update your question with the additional comment. Putting it in a comment makes it difficult to understand what you need exactly.

Comment: Please post the AMPScript code that you have so far.

Comment: @adam I posted the code...but I am new to this So code didn't come in proper format.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs, In sourceStr I have HTML Data that[that have multiple URL] But My code takes just First one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate through the entire string.  I'd suggest utilizing the [BuildRowSetFromString()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/BuildRowSetFromString.html) function.  Something like this:

```
%%[
var @t, @rs, @rc
set @t = 'some text, then a <a href="http://someurl.com?p=1" alias="link1">link1</a>. some more text and <a alias="link2" href="http://someurl.com?p=2">link2</a> and more text'
set @t = replace(replace(@t,"<","&lt;"),">","&gt;")
set @rs = buildrowsetfromstring(@t," ")
set @rc = rowcount(@rs)

set @newParm = "&n=1"

outputline(concat("<p><b>original</b></p>",@t))

set @t2 = ""

/* iterate through rowset of words */
for @i = 1 to @rc do

  set @r = row(@rs, @i)
  set @s = field(@r,1)

  set @s2 = @s

  /* of the word starts with href */
  if indexOf(@s,"href") > 0 then

     set @qc = 0

     /* iterate through each character */
     for @j = 1 to length(@s) do

       /* if you encounter a double quote... */
       if substring(@s,@j,1) == '"' then
         set @qc = add(@qc,1)

         /* if it's the second one, insert the new parameter */
         if @qc == 2 then
           set @first = substring(@s,1,subtract(@j,1))
           set @last = substring(@s,@j,length(@s))
           set @s2 = concat(@first,@newParm,@last)
         endif

       endif

     next @j

  endif
  /* concatenate new string, word by word */
  set @t2 = concat(@t2, " ",@s2)

next @i


outputline(concat("<p><b>new</b></p>",@t2))

set @t2 = replace(replace(@t2,"&lt;","<"),"&gt;",">")

]%%
```

Comment: "set @t = replace(replace(@t,"<","&lt;"),">","&gt;")" this code replacing HTML code in text???  and one this what will put if in URL doesn't have '?' first it should track '?' then only we have to add '&test' otherwise '?test'....Please guide me on this..

Comment: I encode the `<` and `>` at the beginning in order to utilize the `buildrowsetfromstring()` function.. then do the reverse at the end.  The function won't parse properly if you don't do that part.

Comment: I'll leave the handling of the `&` vs `?` to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
%%[
VAR @sourceStr

SET @sourceStr = 'str'

SET @regEx1 = '.*(href="[a-zA-Z0-9:/&=?.$-_#]+).*'
SET @append = "&MC=HTML5"
VAR @result
SET @result = RegExMatch(@sourceStr, @regEx1, 0, "IgnoreCase", "Multiline")
SET @TaggedUTL= Concat(RegExMatch(@sourceStr, @regEx1, 1),@append)

IF Length(@result) > 0 THEN
    SET @outPut = Replace(@sourceStr,RegExMatch(@sourceStr, @regEx1,1), @TaggedUTL) /*It takes only first URL*/
ENDIF 

]%%
Replaced:  %%=v(@outPut)=%%<br>
```

Comment: In SET @sourceStr='HTML Data' where have some URL LIke (http://Xxyz.com/?Wt.mc_id=IG15W2NWTN&loc=zOTlocz&prod=zWAz&prod=zWSz&tech=zCLz&prog=zOTprogz&type=zEVz&media=zOTmediaz&country=zUSz) and [Link] (https://XXyz.com/?target=reg20.jsp&eventid=897605&sessionid=1&key=2F3D1EB963D9DB7738BF2877DFFDBA01&partnerref=Social&sourcepage=register&loc=zOTlocz&prod=zWAz&tech=zsecz&prog=zOTprogz&type=zOTtypez&media=zWCz&country=zUSz) with href= but my code just take first URL...Please Help on this

Comment: you probably [don't want to use a regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: @charles Actually My HTML code that is inside the DE field... here I am trying to find the 'Href=' then I have to Append some text at the last of URL then Whole HTML thing will come up with that.....But here I am successfully getting only one 'Href=' not others.....

Comment: what happens if someone is writing an email about how to write html, so `href="http://google.com"` is part of the text?

Comment: @charles it will never be... adam have give me fine solution on this.